# How would I create a pass-through query with a parameter that depends on user input via a Microsoft Access form?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, parameters

In Microsoft Access, I have a bit of trouble using pass-through queries, or at least trouble when it comes to a parameter.

I have a main form used for searching (data source is a local table of employees with id's), so the end user enters in a employee id and hits the search button.

A subform is supposed to show the results. Right now the subform is not built off of anything, but the results should come from a pass through query, which points to a stored procedure in SQL Server that takes a parameter. That procedure with its parameter queries a different data source (`communication_log_tbl`) located in SQL Server, and ultimately returns data to the subform in MS Access showing us the results.

So to break it down the process I'm looking at is:

- Search employee id [Main form]
- -> employee id sent to pass through query as a parameter
- -> stored procedure runs in SQL Server with the parameter we passed
- -> returns results to the [subform]

**Things to note**

- Main form data source is a local employee table.
- Subform data source is currently nothing but *I THINK* should be based off the pass through query, or at least the table the pass through query references which is called `communication_log_tbl` located in SQL Server.

My main issue right now may be logic but this is what I tried so far.

1. The pass through query when hardcoding a employee id works when switching form design view to datasheet view.
   For example:

   EXEC [GetCommunicationLogs] @Param911Number = 'Employee_ID_85';

   **Note**: `GetCommunicationLogs` is the name of the stored procedure located in SQL Server. Which is just a select statement with a parameter for `employee_id`.

   **Problem**: I can't hardcode an employee id because it dependent upon what the user enters in the main_form search box. So what do I do here for almost a variable or placeholder?
2. Logic: I don't understand how the main form which has an entirely different data source can pass the employee id to the subform which should somehow be accessing the pass through query and passing that employee id.

Answer (score 0):

Use VBA to create a pass through query and assign this as record source to your sub form. Each time the employee is changed, update the SQL of the pass through query and assign it new to the sub form.

It would make sense to create a function who does this so that you just have to give the employee ID to the function. Example:

```vb
Public Function SPRecordsourceWithParameter(strStoredProcedure As String, ParamArray varParameter() As Variant) As String

    Dim qdf             As DAO.QueryDef
           Dim strParameter    As String
           Dim strPassThrough  As String
           Dim db As DAO.Database
    
        Set db = CurrentDb()
          
       strPassThrough = "pt" & strStoredProcedure
       strPassThrough = Replace(strPassThrough, ".", "_")
       
       On Error Resume Next
       db.QueryDefs.Delete strPassThrough
       On Error GoTo 0
       
       Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(strPassThrough)
       strParameter = Parameterlist(varParameter)
       
       With qdf
          .Connect = GetConnectionString()
          .SQL = "EXEC " & strStoredProcedure & " " & strParameter
       End With
       
       SPRecordsourceWithParameter = strPassThrough
    End Function
    
    
Public Function Parameterlist(ByVal varParameter As Variant) As String

       Dim strParameter  As String
       Dim i             As Integer
    
       For i = LBound(varParameter) To UBound(varParameter)
          Select Case VarType(varParameter(i))
             Case vbString
                If varParameter(i) = "NULL" Then
                   strParameter = strParameter & ", " & varParameter(i)
                Else
                   varParameter(i) = Replace(varParameter(i), "'", "''")
                   strParameter = strParameter & ", '" & varParameter(i) & "'"
                End If
             Case vbEmpty, vbNull
                strParameter = strParameter & ", NULL"
             Case vbBoolean
                strParameter = strParameter & ", " & IIf(varParameter(i), 1, 0)
             Case Else
                ' numeric Values
                strParameter = strParameter & ", " & Replace(CStr(varParameter(i)), ",", ".")
          End Select
       Next i
       If Len(strParameter) > 0 Then
          strParameter = Mid(strParameter, 3)
       End If
       Parameterlist = strParameter
    End Function
```

You use then in the after update event of your employee field the code:

```
Me.[My Subform name].form.RecordSource = SPRecordsourceWithParameter("YourStoredProcedure", YourEmployeeID)
```

If the employee ID is a text field then use

```
"YourEmployeeID"
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for the feedback.
I wrote the following code and it seems to work, but im not sure if it really uses the pass through query. Again i not only need it to work but i need to make sure speed is the name of the game, hence the pass through query utilization. 

- please note i dropped the stored procedure and changed the forms and query names. 

Main form = "Search_com_test2
Subform = "Subform_B"
pass through query = "P_T_qry"

Comment: Private Sub Command18_Click()
'1. Get the PatientID from the main form
Dim patientID As Variant
patientID = Forms("Search_com_test2").Controls("Search_field_txt_box").Value

'3. Build the SQL statement with the parameter
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM WTC_Communication_Log_TEST_vERS WHERE [911#] = '" & patientID & "';"

'5. Set the parameter value in the pass-through query
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("P_T_qry").SQL = strSQL

Comment: '6. Open a DAO recordset using the pass-through query
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("P_T_qry", dbOpenSnapshot)

'7. Requery the subform to reflect the changes
Me!Subform_B.Requery
End Sub

Comment: And to save world poverty, and not write a bunch of code? See my posted answer....

Answer (score 0):

So, create a passthough query in Access. Set returns records = false.
Let's call the PT query qryPGetCom

You can then use this code:

```
 dim sEID    as string
 sEID = "Employee_ID_85"

 WITH currentDB.QueryDefs("qryPGetCom")
    .SQL = "EXEC [GetCommunicationsLogs] @Param911Number = '" & sEIT & "'"
    .execute
 END WITH
```

So, above should work just fine. So, in above, I set sEID to a value in code for this demo, however you can certainly in code set sEID to whatever  you want say like this:

```
  sEID = forms!SomeForm!EmpID
```